# "rsync" was not detected as installed in your guest machine

Tags: docker, vagrant, boot2docker, vagrantfile

I'm trying to setup Vagrant with docker as a provider but when running

```
vagrant up --provider=docker --debug
```

I get this error:

> "rsync" was not detected as installed in your guest machine. This
>   is required for rsync synced folders to work. In addition to this,
>   Vagrant doesn't know how to automatically install rsync for your
>   machine, so you must do this manually.

Full log here:
http://pastebin.com/zCTSqibM

**Vagrantfile**

```
require 'yaml'

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  user_config = YAML.load_file 'user_config.yml'

  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.build_dir = "."
    d.has_ssh = true
    d.ports = user_config['port_mapping']
    d.create_args = ["--dns=127.0.0.1","--dns=8.8.8.8", "--dns=8.8.4.4"]
    d.build_args = ['--no-cache=true']   end

  config.vm.hostname = "dev"

  config.ssh.username = "it"   config.ssh.port = 22   config.ssh.private_key_path = ["./initial_ssh_key", user_config['ssh_private_key_path']]   config.ssh.forward_agent = true

end
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:jessie MAINTAINER IT <it@email.com>

RUN echo 'exit 0' > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d

RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections

RUN apt-get update RUN apt-get upgrade -y RUN apt-get install sudo apt-utils -y

RUN apt-get -y install sysvinit-core sysvinit sysvinit-utils RUN cp /usr/share/sysvinit/inittab /etc/inittab RUN apt-get remove -y --purge
--auto-remove systemd libpam-systemd systemd-sysv

RUN apt-get install ssh -y

RUN addgroup --system it RUN adduser --system --disabled-password
--uid 1000 --shell /bin/bash --home /home/it it RUN adduser it it RUN adduser it sudo

RUN echo "it ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

ADD initial_ssh_key.pub /home/it/.ssh/authorized_keys RUN chown it:it /home/it/ -R RUN echo "Host * \n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config

CMD exec /sbin/init
```

**Note:** 
I'm on Mac OS X 10.12 and I've installed vagrant, virtualbox and docker I have *rsync* installed and added to my PATH in the host machine.
Also, the same vagrant and docker configs works perfectly on a ubuntu host.

How do I install rsync in the guest machine? Or is something else wrong with my config? Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see you exposing any ports on a docker, try exposing `873` or whatever `rsync` is using with `d.expose = [873]`

Comment: still the same error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to give the **alternative boot2docker box** a try: https://github.com/dduportal/boot2docker-vagrant-box 
as it **contains rsync** while the hashicorp/boot2docker, which is used by default, seems to lack this!

If doing so, you must add the follwong line to your docker provider config (of course adopted to your system):

`d.vagrant_vagrantfile = "../path/to/Vagrantfile"`

This is because you're changing the docker provider host vm as described in the [vagrant docker provider documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/docker/basics.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `rsync` to your Docker file, somewhere in one of your `apt-get` lines. Linux hosts use NFS by default, that's why it works on your Ubuntu.

Normally Vagrant tries to install `rsync` on a guest machine, if that fails - it notifies you with that error message. More info on [vagrant website](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/rsync.html#prerequisites) (3rd paragraph in "Prerequisites" chapter)

Comment: I've tried this already but doesn't seems to work: added ```RUN apt-get install rsync -y```in dockerfile, same error message. Something is wrong with vagrant / vbox :/

Comment: It's not `vbox` - you are using `docker` as a provider: `config.vm.provider "docker"`

Comment: any ideas why it's failing then? I'm seeing this in the logs just before the rsync error message :


[default] GuestAdditions versions on your host (5.0.16) and guest (4.3.28 r100309) do not match.
The guest's platform ("linux") is currently not supported, will try generic Linux method...
Copy iso file /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso into the box /tmp/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 5.0.16 - guest version is 4.3.28 r100309
mkdir: can't create directory '/tmp/selfgz10164313': No such file or directory